# Extracting info from curl -v -X POST

Tags: curl, logging, grep

I am running a curl command as follows:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds=c8f13848-b484-4e40-baac-29a5d3670ce7,8d42156a-8af9-42ac-92a1-77a95c22f3c2,408e09a8-f42f-4cb3-b24f-26c29b476150&shortAudio=true" -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:$apikey_SpeakerRecog" --data-binary @req.wav`
```

The command calls a Microsoft speaker identification API and matches my recorded `.wav` against the profile IDs I have on system. I am after the profile ID it matched to.

I get a detailed log, but the log does not tell me which profile ID was accepted, it just says "accepted". In the log, there is an entry on operation-location which has an ID. I need to use this ID in another curl command to then get the profile ID.

I am really struggling to get this operation ID from the log. I was going to use grep to extract the ID, but I am struggling to save the log to a file or against a variable to then use grep. I have tried writing saving the output in text file but the text file is blank.

I need help extracting the `operationID` from the operation-location parameter of the log.

See part of log below:

```
Content-Length: 160044
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
  0  156k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0} [data not shown]
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Expires: -1
Operation-Location: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/operations/6cbd497c-652f-4723-b5a2-4087af4a01c9
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: I thought I did that. Are you referring to the Curl command?

Comment: Your question has now been formatted by Benjamin W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **sed** for this:

```
sed -n -r 's/^.*Operation-Location:.*\/([^/]+)$/\1/p'
```

example usage:

```
$ sed -n -r 's/^.*Operation-Location:.*\/([^/]+)$/\1/p' file
6cbd497c-652f-4723-b5a2-4087af4a01c9
```

Now, the issue of capturing the output of `curl`: curl writes the output to stderr, so you need to redirect that. Also you should disable the progress and displaying error codes with the option `--silent`, like:

```
curl -v --silent https://whatever.you.li.ke 2>&1
```

Next, you can pipe that into your sed/grep call:

```
curl -v --silent https://whatever.you.li.ke 2>&1 | sed -n -r 's/Operation-Location:.*\/([^/]+)$/\1/p'
```

OR
you can write the output of the curl command to a file with usage of the `--stderr` option:

```
curl -v --silent --stderr curl.log https://whatever.you.li.ke
```

and unleash your grep/sed wizardry on that log file.

Comment: Thanks. Please ignore **. I had added those thinking the editor would make the text bold for clarity, but it didn work so I am have updated it to exclude **. So for that sed command, you are assuming the log is already stored in file and you are then reading the file. That make sense, but I am struggling to create the log file in the first place. I am running that curl command on linux cmd, but am unable to save the output to anything. I added > log_file.txt at the end of the curl command but it produces a blank file. I dont know if it is do with this specific curl command? any ideas?

Comment: Changed my answer addressing your real issue.

Comment: almost there It is returning the following: > 6cbd497c-652f-4723-b5a2-4087af4a01c9 ... there is '>' at the front of it. I am not very familar with sed. Could you quickly explain some of the commands you've used.

Comment: You can find all about sed (stream editor) on https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/. Simply put, it's used to filter text, apply some operation on it, and then output the modified text. That's exactly what where doing here: we're selecting the line with `Operation-Location` and print some part of that line to the output. To get rid of the `>` we need to change the regex a bit. See adapted answer.

Comment: worked well...but when i was using the string downstream in another curl command URL...got an issue saying "invalid characters in URL". Turns out there was a non-ascii CR character at the end of the string which i got rid of by saving the ID as a variable lets say UserOpID and then applying $UserOpID | tr -d '\r' to it. It then worked fine downstream

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -oP 'https.*\/\K.*(?=\*\*)' log_file
6cbd497c-652f-4723-b5a2-4087af4a01c9
```

The command would print the patterns between last slash `/` to `**`

Comment: Thanks. Please ignore **. I had added those thinking the editor would make the text bold for clarity, but it didn work so I am have updated it to exclude **. So for that grep command, you are assuming the log is already stored in log_file and you are then reading the log_file. That make sense, but I am struggling to create the log file in the first place. I am running that curl command on linux cmd, but am unable to save the output to anything. I added > log_file.txt at the end of the curl command but it produces a blank file. I dont know if it is do with this specific curl command? any ideas?